# PHP in Apache and CLI using same php.ini file but in Apache ImageMagick has no supported formats

Tags: php, imagemagick, ubuntu-14.04, imagick, bitnami

What would cause this discrepancy in the supported formats?

`php -ini` on the command line:

```
imagick

imagick module => enabled
imagick module version => 3.4.3
imagick classes => Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator
Imagick compiled with ImageMagick version => ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2017-07-31 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Imagick using ImageMagick library version => ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2017-07-31 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
ImageMagick copyright => Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
ImageMagick release date => 2017-07-31
ImageMagick number of supported formats:  => 213
ImageMagick supported formats => 3FR, A, AAI, AI, ART, ARW, AVI, AVS, B, BGR, BGRA, BIE, BMP, BMP2, BMP3, BRF, C, CAL, CALS, CANVAS, CAPTION, CIN, CIP, CLIP, CMYK, CMYKA, CR2, CRW, CUR, CUT, DCM, DCR, DCX, DDS, DFONT, DJVU, DNG, DOT, DPX, EPDF, EPI, EPS, EPS2, EPS3, EPSF, EPSI, EPT, EPT2, EPT3, ERF, EXR, FAX, FITS, FRACTAL, FTS, G, G3, GIF, GIF87, GRADIENT, GRAY, GROUP4, HALD, HDR, HISTOGRAM, HRZ, HTM, HTML, ICB, ICO, ICON, INFO, INLINE, IPL, ISOBRL, J2C, J2K, JBG, JBIG, JNG, JP2, JPC, JPEG, JPG, JPX, K, K25, KDC, LABEL, M, M2V, M4V, MAC, MAP, MAT, MATTE, MEF, MIFF, MNG, MONO, MOV, MP4, MPC, MPEG, MPG, MRW, MSL, MSVG, MTV, MVG, NEF, NRW, NULL, O, ORF, OTB, OTF, PAL, PALM, PAM, PANGO, PATTERN, PBM, PCD, PCDS, PCL, PCT, PCX, PDB, PDF, PDFA, PEF, PES, PFA, PFB, PFM, PGM, PGX, PICON, PICT, PIX, PJPEG, PLASMA, PNG, PNG24, PNG32, PNG8, PNM, PPM, PREVIEW, PS, PS2, PS3, PSB, PSD, PTIF, PWP, R, RADIAL-GRADIENT, RAF, RAS, RGB, RGBA, RGBO, RLA, RLE, SCR, SCT, SFW, SGI, SHTML, SR2, SRF, STEGANO, SUN, SVG, SVGZ, TEXT, TGA, THUMBNAIL, TIFF, TIFF64, TILE, TIM, TTC, TTF, TXT, UBRL, UIL, UYVY, VDA, VICAR, VID, VIFF, VST, WBMP, WMF, WMV, WMZ, WPG, X, X3F, XBM, XC, XCF, XPM, XPS, XV, XWD, Y, YCbCr, YCbCrA, YUV

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
imagick.locale_fix => 0 => 0
imagick.progress_monitor => 0 => 0
imagick.skip_version_check => 0 => 0
```

.
Output of `phpinfo()` in the browser:

[image: Imagick phpinfo()]

Where both are using `/opt/bitnami/php/etc/php.ini`

```
$ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.5 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that in the Environment section of the Apache phpinfo() output the following environment variables were not set, but they were set in the CLI:

```
MAGICK_CODER_MODULE_PATH
MAGICK_CONFIGURE_PATH
MAGICK_HOME
```

Adding the following to `/opt/bitnami/scripts/setenv.sh` did the trick:

```
##### APACHE ENV #####
MAGICK_HOME=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.7.7/
export MAGICK_HOME
MAGICK_CONFIGURE_PATH=/etc/ImageMagick/
export MAGICK_CONFIGURE_PATH
MAGICK_CODER_MODULE_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.7.7/modules-Q16/coders
export MAGICK_CODER_MODULE_PATH
```

Comment: I've been bashing my head against this problem for a week, and trying to force-set those variables for a day.  This worked.  Thank you.

NOTE: this fix is probably unique to Bitnami VM's.  It looks like the OP is using one of Bitnami's Ubuntu VM's, but it worked for me on a Bitnami's Debian VM's.

Comment: It's definitely unique to Bitnami. The question made reference to Bitnami and was tagged as such. This actually may have been the last time I bothered with a Bitnami deployment. More trouble than they're worth.